# No module named psutil when executed using python filename.py but works perfectly with shebang & chmod

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, chmod, shebang, psutil

consider this code in python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import psutil

def check_disk_usage(disk):
    a=shutil.disk_usage(disk)
    free=a.free/a.total*100
    return free

print(check_disk_usage("/"))
```

when i execute this in terminal using "python health.py". it gives error

```
shambhav@shambhav-Lenovo-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~/Desktop/coursera$ code health.py
shambhav@shambhav-Lenovo-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~/Desktop/coursera$ python health.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "health.py", line 3, in <module>
  import psutil
ImportError: No module named psutil
```

but when i execute like this it works perfectly. why so??

```
shambhav@shambhav-Lenovo-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~/Desktop/coursera$ code health.py
shambhav@shambhav-Lenovo-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~/Desktop/coursera$ chmod +x health.py
shambhav@shambhav-Lenovo-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~/Desktop/coursera$ ./health.py
87.24079278480475
```

Can someone help me with this??

Comment: have you tried lauching with `python3 health.py` ? What `which python` tells you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shebang, you explicitly use `python3`, but not when you launch it from the terminal. Hence, try:

```
python3 health.py
```

In order to understand, try typing `which python` or `python --version` in your terminal. I bet it is not pointing to python3, but python2.

Comment: yeah! got it ... this was so easy..........thank you so much!!

Comment: no worries, happens to the best ! don't forget to mark the question as answered and happy coding